# how display background image in collapsible list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I am trying to display a background image as a mi nus sign when the list is clicked and open it should go fro plus to minus. When you click and hold down on the mouse you see the minus but upon release it goes back to plus and should show minus till it is collapsed. I am including my code. Thanks

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/Tiki16/f7x8fn0a/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Try to track the javascript events for mouse down and up. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) Add on the mousedown event the current button to make it release afterwards so that you can display the plus sign again.

Comment: I should be able to do it purely with css. I did it with an accordion faq.